# Categories not posts at the frontpage

Tags: categories, frontpage

can someone please help, i just need a way to display only categories at the frontpage without posts, visitor will enter the website first what he see is the categories , searched all over the web without success
thanks

Comment: Well what have you tried?  This shouldn't actually be a difficult thing to do but you are going to have to write a custom template or modify some templates in your theme to get this working. But without seeing what you're actually working with it's impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.